# Link to open iTunes from Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, web, app-store

I can open iTunes fine from IE or Safari using an itms:// link. However, when opening on Chrome, the same link doesn't open the desktop program for iTunes.

Does anyone know a link that will open iTunes from Chrome? Apple is able to do it somehow, but it appears from looking at their page source that they may be running some sort of script to do that. I would be open to the possibility of using a script if someone could point me in the direction of how to do so, but ideally a single link that would work across browsers is ideal.

Edit: It appears iTunes uses an itmss:// link when opening iTunes, I've been using an itms:// link. However, copying and pasting the exact link Chrome tells me its opening when I click "View in iTunes" into the omnibar of Chrome only Google searches the link, it doesn't actually open iTunes. Any ideas as to what "extra things" Apple is doing with that link to get it to open in iTunes?

Comment: You tagged iOS, but you mentioned about IE. Are you working on iPhones or in Windows PC? by the way, `itms://` links are not cross-platform-supported; each item has its corresponding `http://` version, use it.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this for anyone finding this page in the future. You can't type the itms:// link directly into the omnibar. When I made a simple HTML page with only the link on it and clicked it, it opened iTunes up fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this problem after so many failures. Hope it may work for you.

Well, if you are using VPN, just switch from "Auto mode" to "Global mode". Later, reopen that iTunes page. That's all. It is super easy but useful.

Comment: That's not related at all.